# tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Received a label value of 357436800 which is outside the valid range of [0, 2)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to code a neural network with keras.
Here is how I import my libraries and modules:

```
import keras
import os
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Activation
from keras.layers.core import Dense
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.metrics import categorical_crossentropy
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
```

I want it to output the sucessor of an input. For example, If I input 5, it should output 6.
I create a training dataset with this format for the neural network:

```
data = [2, 5, 12, 300, 123, 52, 8, 64, 112, 6452746, 12638, 799378, 69967, 654, 89, 61, 24, 60, 40, 20385, 999, 764, 7, 357436786]
labels = list(item+1 for item in data)
scaled_train_samples = np.array(data)
train_labels = np.array(labels)
```

I try to test my model out on some data. I want to input it 94 after the training, and hopefully it will output something close to 95.

So I write the following:

```
scaled_test_samples = np.array([94])
```

Then, I read somewhere that to fix my error I need to add this line of code, so I add it here:

```
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
```

It didn't fix my error, but neither did I bother to remove it.

Next, I define my model with the following code:

```
model = Sequential([
    Dense(units=16, input_shape=(1,), activation='relu'),
    Dense(units=32, activation='relu'),
    Dense(units=2, activation='sigmoid')
])
```

I have defined a basic 3 layer neural network. Next, I compile it with the following code:

```
model.compile(
    optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001), 
    loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 
    metrics=['accuracy']
)
```

Once I have a defined and compiled keras neural network ready with me, before predicting it or testing it out, I fit the model.
I do so with the following code:

```
model.fit(
    x=scaled_train_samples, 
    y=train_labels, 
    batch_size=2, 
    epochs=11, 
    shuffle=True, 
    verbose=2
)
```

Now, I have finally finished my neural network. I now try to predict and test out whether 94 outputs 95:

```
predictions = model.predict(
    x=scaled_test_samples, 
    batch_size=10, 
    verbose=1
)
```

Then of course, I print my predictions:

```
print(predictions)
```

Here is some basic information, if it helps:

OS: Windows 10
GPU: No
IDE: Visual Studio Code
Interpreter: Python 3.8.8 64-bit

I've tried running it on linux and once on repl.it, but it still produces the error. Below is the output.

First, it shows me some wierd error but I ignore it since I am not using a GPU:

```
2021-03-08 14:08:11.945167: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2021-03-08 14:08:11.945684: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
```

Then comes the real error. It seems the error is coming from the training process, as the error begins right after it begins the training output 'epoch 1/11'.

```
2021-03-08 14:08:15.192424: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-03-08 14:08:15.193919: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'nvcuda.dll'; dlerror: nvcuda.dll not found
2021-03-08 14:08:15.194352: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:326] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)   
2021-03-08 14:08:15.199531: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:169] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: LAPTOP-78M3QUGV
2021-03-08 14:08:15.200385: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:176] hostname: LAPTOP-78M3QUGV
2021-03-08 14:08:15.201202: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-03-08 14:08:15.202400: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-03-08 14:08:15.285471: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:116] None of the MLIR optimization passes are enabled (registered 2)
Epoch 1/11
2021-03-08 14:08:15.636802: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1763] OP_REQUIRES failed at sparse_xent_op.cc:90 : Invalid argument: Received a label value of 357436800 which is outside the valid range of [0, 2).  Label values: 357436800 13
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Maanav/Desktop/New folder/add.py", line 31, in <module>
    model.fit(
  File "C:\Users\Maanav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1100, in fit
    tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
  File "C:\Users\Maanav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 828, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Maanav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 888, in _call
    return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Maanav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 2942, in __call__
    return graph_function._call_flat(
  File "C:\Users\Maanav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1918, in _call_flat
    return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
  File "C:\Users\Maanav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 555, in call
    outputs = execute.execute(
  File "C:\Users\Maanav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 59, 
in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  Received a label value of 357436800 which is outside the valid range of [0, 2).  Label values: 357436800 13
         [[node sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits (defined at c:/Users/Maanav/Desktop/New folder/add.py:31) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_614]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

Thank you for taking the time to read this question! Any help is deeply appreciated!
Peace out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your target labels need to be zero indexed and the maximum value needs to correspond to your output units in order to use `CategoricalCrossentropy`. Tensorflow knows you have 2 output units and `6452746` is one of your target categories, so it doesn't understand.

This is a regression problem, so use 1 output unit and use `loss='MAE'` or some other regression loss function, without a final activation function.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(1000)
y = x + 1


model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=16, input_shape=(1,), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=32, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1)
])

model.compile('adam', 'mae')

history = model.fit(x, y, epochs=500, verbose=0)

model.predict([96])
```

```
array([[97.32837]], dtype=float32)
```

You could do it as a classification problem, but you would need to convert your targets to zero-indexed categories.